# Write raw disk bytes in Python

Tags: python, raw-disk

I am looking for a way to write raw bytes into a disk image using Python. For example, I have an list containing several characters and I need to write all those characters in different parts of my disk.

In my Python script I need to do something like this: My list **xab** contains all those characters that I need to write in my this and the SelectedSectors list contains the sectors that will be written with each **xab** characters.

```
disk = open("mydisk.img",'ab')
for i in SelectedSectors:
    disk.seek(SelectedSectors[i])
    disk.write(xab[i])
disk.close()
```

I am not sure in how to deal with individual bytes in my disk image using Python. How should I solve this problem?

Best regards,

F.Borges

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am working on a customized disk utility based on Python. It is experimental but basically I require to write raw bytes into specific sectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append mode automatically performs all writes at the end. Open the file in `rb+` mode. `r` prevents truncating the file when it's opened, and `+` allows writing in addition to reading.

Also, `for i in SelectedSectors` sets `i` to the elements of the list, not the indexes; you don't need to index the list inside the loop.

```
with open("mydisk.img",'rb+') as disk:
    for i in SelectedSectors:
        disk.seek(i)
        disk.write(xab[i])
```

Comment: I tried to do this and I am getting this error:

disk.write(xab[i])
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You wrote that `xab` is a list. Obviously it isn't, you need to access it properly/.

Comment: xab = open("stuff.raw", "r") it was read a file and the contents stored in the variable xab

Comment: Try `xab = open("stuff.raw", "r").readlines()` to get a list of lines from the file.

Comment: A file object is not a list. You can loop over it because it's an iterator, but you can't index it.

Comment: Don't forget that the elements of `xab` will end with newline, you might want to strip those off.

Comment: datastream = xab.read() i used this and now i am trying to complete the loop. By using this implementation can I get rid of newline?

Comment: Apparently it worked when i changed the 'rb+' to 'r+' i am still testing the disk image to see if it worked. Let me check to see.

Comment: If you are reading binary data, then instead of trying to get a "list of lines", it's probably better to open the file in binary mode and get a single chunk of bytes: `open("stuff.raw", "rb").read()`.

Comment: If you use `xab.read()` you'll read the entire file as a single string, not a list. You can use `xab[i].rstrip('\n')` to remove the newline.